# Creating an Integer Format?

Tags: c#, int

I'm venturing into networking using C# and I'm trying to create a clean way to send my packets, right now though I'm not going to worry with all of the *Packets enclosed in special characters* stuff that I've been reading about, instead the packet is three digit number dedicated to the front of the data passed to the client. For example, a data string may be the following.

LoginPacket is packet 000.

LoginPacket Data would be "000Username~Password"

I've tried to clean this up, so I could just write things in a cleaner manner, and try something like this

```
SendPacket(000, new string { "data", "parameters" });
```

However, sending the integer 000 is instantly converted to zero.

Is there a way around this, or would I be better off storing it all in a string, such as

```
SendPacket(new string { "000", "data", "params" } );
```

Comment: Yes, you would be better off storing it all in a string, or at least padding the string at some point.

Comment: @minitech ~ You said "Padding" the string? I'm still new to this, what exactly would you mean by that.

Comment: Storing it in a string is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the number to text you need to specify the number of digits.  The number `000` and `0` are both zero. However the string "`000`" and "`0`" are different strings.

Use

```
n.ToString("000");
```

To ensure you get three digits.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with a *Command Type* followed by a *Length* followed by the *Payload*

Then your payloads can be of a similar structure.. so the login command (0) would use a structure that began with a length byte followed by username followed by a second length byte and finally followed by a password.

For example:

> 0155Dan-o8password

Remember that this all comes over the wire as a byte array.. so you read the first 4 bytes (Int32, Command Type)

Then read the next Int32 to figure out the length of the payload.. that's how many bytes you will read in your third read.

Now that you know the Command is login you can implement login-specific reading.

In addition I would suggest you create some extension methods to make this easier.
like:  *Stream.ReadByte*, *Stream.ReadInt32*, *Stream.ReadInt64*, *Stream.ReadString(length)*

Then some application-specific extensions.. like *Stream.ReadLogin*

Comment: The problem is I'm using Java for the server backend, and from the research I've done it likes to receive String Data, instead of Byte[] data.